# jQuery element value to js object ID

Tags: openlayers-2, jquery

I am trying to set the visibility of a layer in Openlayers map according to a checkbox status with a class ".layercheck" and value is the name of the Openlayers layer.

So here is my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="layercheck" value="layer134431245">text
```

And here is JS:

```
   var layer134431245 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(...); 
   $(".layercheck").on( "click", function() {
    var layer = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#"+layer).setVisibility(true);
    } else {
        $("#"+layer).setVisibility(false); 
        }
   });
```

This function and HTML does completely nothing. It also does not give an error in the js console.

So how do I make this work, and switch the layer visibility with any of the checkboxes which have the class "layercheck" and value is the layer ID?

I also understand that the $("#"+layer) is not the layer, but a jQuery object which maybe does not have the properties setVisibility. So then how do I convert a value (string) into a Openlayers layer name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also understand that the $("#"+layer) is not the layer, but a jQuery object which maybe does not have the properties setVisibility

Well, it *definitely* doesn't have `setVisibility` because it's a DOM element (e.g. an HTML div), not an OpenLayers object. If you only have one OpenLayers layer you can simply use its reference:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  layer134431245.setVisibility(true);
} else {
  layer134431245.setVisibility(false);
}
```

But to make your code more general you could use layer's `name` to link between your JS code and the checkboxes (changed names and added another layer to make it more illustrative):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="layercheck" value="layer1">Layer A</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="layercheck" value="layer2">Layer B</input>
```

**JS**:

```
var layerA = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layer1", { ... });
var layerB = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layer2", { ... });

map.addLayers([layerA, layerB]);


$(".layercheck").on("click", function () {
  var layerToCheck = $(this).val();

  var layersWithThisName = map.getLayersByName(layerToCheck);
  for (var i = 0; i < layersWithThisName.length; i++) {
    var l = layersWithThisName[i];
    l.setVisibility($(this).is(":checked"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Although I would probably simplify this with the following:
`$(".layercheck").on( "click", function() {
var layerVis = map.getLayer($(this).val());
layerVis.setVisibility($(this).is(":checked"));
});`

Comment: Correction. This works better:
`$("#maplayers").on( "click", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {var layerId = $(this).val();
var layerObj = map.getLayersByName(layerId);
layerObj[0].setVisibility($(this).is(":checked"));});`

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple layers in a layertree with checkboxes. I have given each layer a option that I call  treeIndex.
On initialization I build the layer tree and set the id of the checkbox to the treeIndex. That ties the checkbox and the layer to each other.

```
function build_layertree() {    // called once on initialization

  var tree = new Array();
  $.each(map.layers, function(index) {
    if (this.options.displayInLayerSwitcher) {
      var idx = this.treeIndex
      if (this.options.visibility) {
        tree[idx] = "<li><input type='checkbox' id='" + idx + "'    checked='checked'/><label  class='layer'>" + this.name + "</label></li>";
      }else{
        tree[idx] = "<li><input type='checkbox' id='" + idx + "'/><label class='layer'>" + this.name + "</label></li>";
        }
    }
  });

  #layertree is a <div> in the html
 //using the treeIndex order my layers as I want in the map layers, i am happy
 for (x=0; x<tree.length; ++x) {
    $("#layertree ul").append(tree[x]);
        }
  return;


}
```

After the layertree is built this calls my toggleLayer function when the checkbox is checked or unchecked

```
$('#layertree input').click(function () {toggleLayer(this.id);});
```

And here is toggleLayer

```
function toggleLayer(id) {
// called when a checkbox is checked/un checked
// id is the the id of the checkbox which is the layer treeIndex, use that to find the layer to toggle
// this is whrere the layer visibility is changed
$.each(map.layers, function(index) {
  if (this.options.displayInLayerSwitcher) {
    if (this.treeIndex == id) {
      this.setVisibility(!this.visibility);
    }
   }    
})
};
```